# Error when use: bpy.data.collections.remove(my_coll) blender 2.8

Tags: python

I not understand if is a bug or is my mistake,that script work fine , but i not understand tipology of error,

ERROR (bke.library): c:\b\win64_cmake_vs2017\win64_cmake_vs2017\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\library.c:242 id_us_min: ID user decrement error: GRMyColl (from '[Main]'): 0 <= 0

Comment: removing a collection the way you mention works fine for me. Are you using the latest build of Blender 2.80? Can you provide more information on what happens before, and what `my_coll` is?

Comment: build is from 25 February, my_col = bpy.data.collections.get('My_Coll'), the operation work fine, but get this error

Comment: Please try today's version from https://builder.blender.org/download/ - I still cannot replicate the issue. A simple `bpy.data.collections.remove(bpy.data.collections.get('colName'))` works fine for me if the collection is present, otherwise throws a `Function.collection does not support a 'None' assignment Collection type` error. The error you post comes from the C code itself, so if it persists, you'll need to file a bug report at https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: Can't replicate this either. Please add code being used and a sample file. Minimal case producing such error, if possible. The error infers that some object (a collection or something  in one maybe) is trying to set its users to less than 0. (subtracting from users <= 0).    For bug report best (from experience with writing some very bad bug reports, one because  I hadn't built against python 3.6) to test with an official build of blender as suggested above by the 'guru.